# Facebook Id changes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

We are revising our Facebook login, is it possible that the user's Facebook Id will change?

We are hearing rumours about the fact that it is possible that the id's will change. I'm aware of the fact that that recently increased their integer size?

We will not replace the Facebook API keys.

Comment: where did you hear those weird rumours? you should always be as detailed as possible in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an App, the IDs will not change - that would be a massive problems for a lot of Apps. You get "App Scoped IDs", so if you use another App, each user will get a different ID again.